# Why isn't my second tabbar page showing in ONSEN UI

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui

I'm relatively new to ONSEN UI, I am using a tabbar layout and also pushing to different pages when an "option" is pressed, this is my solution for it to do so:

```
<ons-navigator id="myNavigator" animation="fade" page="timer.html">
    <ons-page>
        <ons-tabbar swipeable animation='slide' position="bottom">
            <ons-tab page="classic.html" label="CLASSIC" icon="fa-smile" active>
            </ons-tab>
            <ons-tab page="drinking.html" label="DRINK" icon="fa-beer" badge="NEW">
            </ons-tab>
        </ons-tabbar>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">Truth or Dare - Unlimited</div>
                <div class="right menu">
                    <ons-toolbar-button>
                        <ons-icon icon="fa-ellipsis-v"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
            </ons-toolbar>
        </ons-toolbar>
    </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>


<template id="classic.html">
    <ons-navigator id="myNavigator" animation="fade" page="classic.html">
        <ons-page id="classic">
            <div class="options">
                <div class="option vibrate easy">
                    <ons-ripple color="#c9446c" background="#C3073F"></ons-ripple>
                    <img src="icons/easy.png" class="level-img" alt="Easy">
                    <h2>Easy</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="option vibrate normal">
                    <ons-ripple color="#c9446c" background="#C3073F"></ons-ripple>
                    <img src="icons/normal.png" class="level-img" alt="Normal">
                    <h2>Normal</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="option vibrate hard">
                    <ons-ripple color="#c9446c" background="#C3073F"></ons-ripple>
                    <img src="icons/hard.png" class="level-img" alt="Hard">
                    <h2>Hard</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="option locked vibrate nightmare">
                    <ons-ripple color="#c9446c" background="#C3073F"></ons-ripple>
                    <img src="icons/nightmare.png" class="level-img" alt="Nightmare">
                    <h2>Nightmare</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="option locked vibrate random">
                    <ons-ripple color="#c9446c" background="#C3073F"></ons-ripple>
                    <img src="icons/random.png" class="level-img" alt="Random">
                    <h2>Random</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="option locked vibrate couple">
                    <ons-ripple color="#c9446c" background="#C3073F"></ons-ripple>
                    <img src="icons/couple.png" class="level-img" alt="Couple">
                    <h2>Couple</h2>
                    <p>(Dirty)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
</template>

<template id="drinking.html">
    <ons-navigator id="myNavigator" animation="fade" page="drinking.html">
    <ons-page id="drinking">
        <p>PAGE 2</p>
    
    </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
</template>
```

No custom js is used for the tabbar elements.

Why isn't the content on my second tabbar page showing? I've tried removing the ons-navigator from the drinking template but still no progress, now I'm stuck.

What am I doing wrong?